# javafx error - weird character(english, number) (javaSE-11, UTF-8) (mac vscode)

Tags: java, javafx, utf-8, character

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

I’m  bad at english, so understand me
When I run the program (which is using javafx), the error occur. (like the picture)
English and number is showed weirdly.
I'm using javaSE-11 and UTF-8.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Never seen this before. Like JosefZ said, we're going to need a minimal reproducible example to see what may cause this problem.